# Trouble Installing PairVPN with Wine

Tags: linux, wine

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and installed Wine 7.0

I am trying to install [PairVPN](https://pairvpn.com/).

I right click the exe file and run it with Wine. It goes through the installation but then it fails with an error message:

> Fail to install PairVPN Network Driver, error=11001

I'm very new with Linux, but is it difficult to install a network driver like this with Wine?

- Any ideas how to go about troubleshooting this?
- Or can anyone try to get it to work themselves?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it turned out impossible. Wine is a runtime for programs, not for drivers.

Comment: You pick the one VPN that doesn't support Linux?

Comment: I am pretty sure (95%+) that what you are trying to do will not work.  Long time work for me with VPN.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I wanted to know.

I use PairVPN because it's the only VPN that you can install on both your phone and your PC, tether the PC with hotspot, and it hides the hotspot data as regular mobile data to get around the data limit. Another VPN app exists but it's Android only.

Since this is impossible, any idea how I could achieve this in Ubuntu? I already tried setting TTL to like 65, but that alone doesn't work.

Cheers again in advance

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/RiFi2k/unlimited-tethering

Comment: That does not work with iOS, @YisroelTech . It's Android only and that's an issue the OP acknowledged.